# Logistic regression: why MSE working better than Cross Entropy?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic

My model has **6 input** features populated with continuous values (MinMax from -1 to 1) and **3 output**.

The aim is to mutually identify **one of three classes** (multiclass single label).

I did tests for about a month trying out different configurations of the model using **Mean Square Error** as a cost function, getting some (not so exciting) results.

Then I read that for the Logistic Regression the MSE is absolutely wrong so I tried to use the (Softmax) **Cross Entropy**.

The problem is that using this function regardless of the model structure (layer number / number of neurons / activation functions) learning does not seem to work or at least the result is worse: the loss increases after a few epochs and accuracy is very low. What did i do wrong?

**Old model** (best configuration):

- samples: 5100
- batch size: 100
- learning rate: 0.0001
- loss function: MeanSquaredError
- eval function: MeanAbsoluteError
- 3 input
- 1 hidden layer with 6 neurons, ativation: Tanh
- 3 output, activation: linear
- n. of epochs before loss increase: **8640**
- result: train loss=**0,0040**;  eval loss=**0,369**

**New model** (best configuration):

- samples: 5100
- batch size: 100
- learning rate: 0.01
- loss function: CrossEntropyWithSoftmax
- eval function: ClassificationError
- 3 input
- 1 hidden layer with 1 neurons, ativation: Tanh
- 3 output, activation: linear
- n. of epochs before loss increase: **2640**
- result: train loss=**0,0049**;  eval loss=**0,457**

Comment: You can't compare loss numbers between models with different loss functions. It's apples and oranges. You need an objective metric, such as accuracy or AUC-ROC.

Comment: Work better as judged using what?

Comment: thank you, I learned a new thing, I made a wrong assumption

Answer (score 1):

The error in reasoning is that the loss values are not directly comparable; these losses measure different things, so it's not possible to compare them.

Because these measure different things, model 1 could have lower MSE than model 2 but higher cross-entropy; or model 1 could have lower MSE and lower cross-entropy. Instead, just measure the thing you care about for both models: get the model predictions and compute the loss/figure of merit in the usual way.

Instead, you could measure both models according to MSE or cross-entropy, or measure both models according to a third quantity (e.g. ROC AUC).